# What is the best way to create a JUnit test case for the isSorted() method?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, junit, junit4

What is the issue with the provided JUnit test case that tests the `isSorted()` method? The method simply checks if an array of ints is in ascending order. I am trying to thoroughly test the method but am not sure where to start. For example: check if array is empty or has only one element in it. Appreciate any help.

```
public class CheckArray {

    /**
     * Returns true if the given array is sorted in ascending order.
     */
    public static boolean isSorted(int[] a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
            if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

public class CheckArrayTest {
    @Test
    public void isSorted() {
        int[] array = { 2, 1 };
        CheckArray haha = new CheckArray(array);
        assertFalse(haha.isSorted(null));
    }
```

Comment: Why are you instantiating `CheckArray`? Where's the constructor? What's this `isIntArraySorted` method? Why are you passing null?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, copied the method over wrong. However, I am a beginner and a bit lost, but I am passing null in an attempt to check for an empty array.

Comment: Null != empty. And you shouldn't be calling a static method from an instance. And what's `array` for?

Comment: `array` is the creation of an array of ints to test the `isSorted` method

Comment: But you're passing in null, not `array`. You haven't posted any code that actually uses `array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the result if the array is empty or has one element are reasonable tests.

Also check:

- 2-element arrays with equal elements
- 2 element arrays with unequal elements in both orders
- 3 element arrays with the largest element at the beginning, middle and end position.

I'm not sure I'd test much else (maybe the null input case). Ultimately you just need the test to give you reasonable confidence in its correctness; you can add many more tests without increasing that confidence.

Alternatively, you can structure your tests around your belief about how the method works, e.g.

- If I have an array for which this method returns true, what does it return if I add an element {less than, equal to, greater than} the last element to the end? (Hopefully false, false, true)
- If I have an array for which this method returns false, what does it return if I add an element {less than, equal to, greater than} the last element to the end? (Hopefully false in all cases)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to create unit tests, is before creating the actual method you test.

You analyse what your method is supposed to do, and how it should function for each and every possible input. In which cases does it return true? For which input does it return false? When should an exception be thrown? ...

And you write a unit test for each of these cases.
Once you did that, you write the actual method, and see if it works conform your unit tests.

EDIT: also very important, test methods that actually exist. You are testing the  `isIntArraySorted` method, but that method doesn't exist, you should be testing the `isSorted` method.